# who controls the price of BTC?

Tags: exchange-rate, price-discovery

***latest edit [ how does the whole world know the price this two people agreed in the same second they decided to do the trade? while most of transactions run anonymously. ]***

i also wanna ask how does the BTC prices are posted and moveable every second automatically allover the world around the same price range.

is there's an AI for the BTC who're placing and changing its prices based on math for example with an open source to understand how it works ?

[not convincing answers](https://bitcoin.stackexchange.com/questions/60653/who-decides-the-price-of-bitcoin)

Comment: the point is not why all are the same price for sure they will all do similar prices, the point is deciding the price range

Comment: the question is why the btc price is $10,371.68 now, and 2 seconds ago $10,370.63. based on my work for years in the fx market we know there is an AI software run to make the daily and instant small movements to move the market for the traders until whales trade. this softwares is owned by banks. as the source of prices comes from them. now i am trying to understand and discover the same for the btc. where are all prices getting the source of market movement ? did satoshi for example create beside the BTC an AI beside it that decides its prices based on the blockchain transactions? if not, how

Comment: This is not a place for conspiracy theories. The price you see is simply the last price any two people anywhere choose to trade at. There are bots involved written by people who have various strategies, but ultimately the choice to trade and at what price is made by those whose money it is. There is nothing more to it.

Comment: okay, how does the whole world know the price this two people agreed in the same second they decided to do the trade? while most of transactions run anonymously.

Comment: They get published by exchanges. Of course people are free to trade outside of exchanges, and their price is not known to the world. The vast majority of trading happens in open markets, however.

Comment: thank you very much. i need to mark your reply as best answer and situation as solved, but your comment seems not direct answer to be able to mark it, i cant find the button to press it

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> who controls the price of BTC?

No single person.

Like any market, the price is determined by the individual buyers and sellers.

Since most buyers and sellers are human, the price they are willing to buy or sell at depends in part on irrational or emotional factors in part driven by news about various aspects of the global economy as well as news about cryptocurrencies in general and news related to Bitcoin specifically.

Some buyers or sellers may attempt to manipulate the market but, so far as I know, there is nothing in the Bitcoin peer-to-peer protocols that would facilitate this in any unique or special way.

---

> did satoshi for example create beside the BTC an AI beside it that decides its prices based on the blockchain transactions?

No, AFAIK.

Evidence suggests that the person or people behind the name Satoshi Nakamoto are no longer active in the Bitcoin world, certainly not in Bitcoin development. It is of course possible that they are active under another name but there is no way to tell. This part is unanswerable.

So far as I know, there is no significant evidence that price movements involving BTC in currency exchanges act in any way that would contradict what one might expect from reading Satoshi Nakamoto's whitepaper.

I've seen no evidence that there is a AI active in the BTC marketplace that acts any differently (ie. with any special privileges) to any AI active in other currecy markets (e.g. the USD-EUR market)

So far as I know, there are no whitepapers or emails published by  Satoshi Nakamoto that refer to an AI intended to manipulate or determine exchange rates between BTC and another currency.

---

Footnotes:

This Q&A website is not intended nor suited for discussion in general, it is also not suited to examination of conspiracy theories. There may or may not be other places where those kinds of discussion can occur.

Answer (score 0):

The price of any asset on a market is determined by the last trade that came to pass: whenever a buy order and a sell offer overlap, the current price has been found. Exchanges publish their order books at least to their customers if not publicly altogether.

> i also wanna ask how does the BTC prices are posted and moveable every second automatically allover the world around the same price range.

When prices differ across different markets, there is an opportunity for market makers to do arbitrage: They buy the asset where it is cheap, and sell it where it is valuable. Moving the asset from one market to another may incur significant friction, e.g. maintaining fiat balances denominated in various currencies, withdrawal fees, or transaction fees to move cryptocurrencies. As long as there is a significant price gap, the market makers are profiting from arbitrage. When the prices get close to matching the cost of the friction exceeds the gains from arbitrage. Given that all of this data is digitally available and the arbitrage is highly automizable, market makers use trade bots to close arbitrage opportunities in moments. In other words, markets converge in price because it is profitable for market makers to facilitate price convergence.

Comment: thank you very much and yes we arbitrage in the forex but we know the source of the prices there.