# If the prices of virtual currencies on multiple platforms are different, can you buy low and sell high to make a profit?

Tags: blockchain

I have observed that the prices will be different, can I earn the difference?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Why don't people buy at one exchange and sell at another?](https://bitcoin.stackexchange.com/q/12670/13866) or  [Is anyone taking advantage of different prices across exchanges?](https://bitcoin.stackexchange.com/questions/9015/is-anyone-taking-advantage-of-different-prices-across-exchanges)

Answer (score 1):

This is called [arbitrage](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Arbitrage).  It is theoretically possible to make money this way.  Whether it is practically possible is another question.

There was a feature of the market known as the '[Kimchi Premium](https://www.coindesk.com/bitcoins-kimchi-premium-evaporates-as-crackdown-price-sell-off-cool-retail-fervor)', where it looked like this should have been possible with South Korean markets.  However the capital controls and other regulations made this difficult or impossible to exploit.  It is possible you are missing some forex complexity.

Comment: Yes, I should think about it. In terms of withdrawal fees, blockchain fees, and time lag, it is feasible for profit> fees